# How to update a field in a layer with the DBSCAN algorithm using the Graphic Modeler QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, clustering

As you can see in the screenshots, I have a vector layer 'POINT_LAYER' with an "IDCLUSTER" field ready to be updated.

I am also using Graphic Modeler to prepare a processing workflow to calculate the clusters of the DBSCAN algorithm:

[image]

My goal is to create a simple workflow that automates, from the Graphic Modeler, the update vector layer field, without creating a new layer.

In the Clusters option, I have chosen 'Model Input' as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

At the moment, this test does not come close to my goal. I am not sure if this goal can be achieved with the requirements I am approaching.

Is it possible to achieve this goal with this approach, and how could I achieve it?

**Possible idea for a solution**

My last approach to a possible solution, which still does not work, is the following (screenshot below).

My idea is to use the expression `attribute(get_feature('Clusters', 'fid', "fid"), 'CLUSTER_ID')` to relate the value of the "CLUSTER_ID" that creates the temporary layer 'Clusters' to transfer it to the initial layer.

[image]

[image]

[image]